# genymotion上でのmonacaアプリのファイル保存先が分かりません

Tags: monaca, genymotion

monacaクラウドIDEとAndroidエミュレータのgenymotionで開発をしています。
monacaのcordovaFileプラグインを使ってAndroidのローカルストレージにCSVファイルを書き出したいと考えています。

genymotion上のmonacaデバッガ―でコードの動作を確認しており、ファイルは出力されていると思います。しかし、genymotion上に「esファイルエクスプローラー」をインストールして出力されるはずのファイルを探したのですが、見当たりません。

また、クラウドIDEでビルドしたapkファイルを同じくgenymotionにインストールして動作させてみてもやはりファイルは見当たりません。

このようなやり方は見当違いなのでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

3/31追記
ネットからコピーしたものですが、以下がindex.htmlの内容です。

```
【index.html】 

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PhoneGap</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.0.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

  <script>

      function success(parent) {
        console.log("親ディレクトリの名前: " + parent.name);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("新しいディレクトリの作成中にエラーが発生しました: " + error.code);
    }


  //+++++++ write +++++++
    function writeFile(){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS_W, fail);
    }

    function gotFS_W(fileSystem) {

        var filename = "data.txt";

        fileSystem.root.getFile(filename, {create: true}, gotFileEntry_W, fail); 
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("newDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, success, fail);
    }


    function gotFileEntry_W(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);

    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {

        writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
            //alert("write success");
        };

        var data = document.getElementById("memo").value;
        writer.write(data);

    }

    //+++++++　read　+++++++
    function readFile(){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS_R, fail);
    }

    function gotFS_R(fileSystem) {
        var filename = "data.txt";

        fileSystem.root.getFile(filename, {create: true}, gotFileEntry_R, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry_R(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readAsText(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            var saved_data = evt.target.result;

            document.getElementById("result").value = saved_data;
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    //error
    function fail(error) {
        alert(error.code);
    }


  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="memo" value="">
  <input type="button" value="書き込み" onClick="writeFile()">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="読み出し" onClick="readFile()">
  <input type="text" id="result" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

` 
 ３/３１追記２

ボタンクリックで以下のコードが走るようにして、sdcardへファイルを移動させようとしたのですが、エラーになってしまいました。
mobi.monaca以外のフォルダに置くこともできるのでしょうか？

```
 //ファイル移動

    function moveTo1(){

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, moveTo1_gotFS, moveTo1_fail);
    console.log('moveTo1');
}
function moveTo1_gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("data.txt", null, moveTo1_gotFileEntry, moveTo1_fail);
    console.log('moveTo1_gotFS');
}
function moveTo1_gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
//  var tmp =fileEntry.fullPath;
//  var parentPath = tmp.substring(0, tmp.lastIndexOf('/'));
//  var parentName = parentPath.substring(parentPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry('sdcard', 'file:///mnt/sdcard/');
    console.log(parentEntry.fullPath);
    console.log(parentEntry.name);
    fileEntry.moveTo(parentEntry, "data2.txt", moveTo1_moveToSuccess, moveTo1_fail);
    console.log('moveTo1_gotFileEntry');
}
function moveTo1_moveToSuccess(entry) {
    var dump = "moveTo1_moveToSuccess\n";
    dump += entry.name+"\n"+entry.fullPath+"\n";
    document.getElementById("dumpAreaFile").value =dump;
     console.log('moveTo1_moveToSuccess');
}
function moveTo1_fail(error){
    alert("moveTo1_fail: " + error.code);

}
```

Comment: 「genymotion」上でデバッグしているので、動かないとかファイルが出力されないということはないです。まずはコードを記載しましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileEntry.toURL()`を実行すれば、どこにファイルが書き込まれたかわかります。

```
function gotFileEntry_W(fileEntry) {
    console.log(fileEntry.toURL());
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}
```

おそらく`file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/files/data.txt`と出力されるはずです。
`/data/data/～`は`ADB for Chrome`のコマンドラインなどで確認することができますが、SDカードまたはそれに相当する領域に書き込めば、`ファイルマネージャー`などのアプリで確認できます。

**SDカードについての追記**
`config.xml`に次の行を追加してください。
詳しい内容はこちらに記載されています。
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/tree/master/doc/ja

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"/>
```

※3/31追記の最初のコードで試してください。
※Monacaデバッガーで追加しても動作しない場合は、同期データを一度削除して再度実行してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ファイルの場所を確認できました！

対象のファイルを移動させようとしているのですが、追記したコードではうまくいかない状況です・・・。

Comment: 追記いただいたコードで、sdcardフォルダに保存できました。
ありがとうございます。